# How to add a resValue from the environment in Gradle Kotlin DSL?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to add a resource value from the environment on my machine via `resValue` using the Gradle Kotlin DSL. My issue is that the desired variable, `BearerToken` is unresolved. The value is stored in my Mac's `Users/myuser/.gradle/gradle.properties` file.

In regular Kotlin DSL, the below worked just fine

`resValue 'string', "bearer_token", BearerToken`

I am converting to the Gradle Kotlin DSL, and have the following

`resValue("string", "bearer_token", BearerToken)`

Gradle sync failed and reported that `BearerToken` is unresolved. There aren't any other APIs I can use.

I tried using `System.getenv("BearerToken")` and it did not work either.

Does anyone know what the issue may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havn't tried this. But properties end up in the `project.properties` map.
So instead of `System.getenv` try: `project.properties.get("BearerToken")`

Answer (score 0):

I just try with

```
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.configure.gradleLocalProperties

gradleLocalProperties(rootDir).getProperty([KEY]) ?:""
```